# Return a boolean value from a list comprehension

Tags: haskell

I'm brand new to haskell and am working through some tutorial problems for a functional programming course I am taking. There is one problem that I am completely stumped on.

Define a function that returns whether a given string contains all numerical values or not (i.e. "123" => True, "1a3" => False). The function must use a list comprehension.

It's this last part that is killing me. It's easy to write without a list comprehension. It's also easy to write a list comprehension with a predicate to ensure that you only put numerical chars into a new list.

```
isNum  =  [ x | x <- xs, x `elem` ['0'..'9'] ]
```

However I'm not sure how to then compare the new list to the original list to check for equality since this is the entire function definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this homework?

Since the list comprehension will only include characters that are numerals, if there are any non-numeric elements, the resulting list will be shorter.

Another approach is to put `isNum xs = [ elem x ['0'..'9'] | x <- xs ]`.  Then you have a list of Boolean values telling you whether each character was a numeral.  You can use a Prelude function to tell you whether all the values were `True` or not.

EDIT: more efficiently, there is also a Prelude function that can tell you whether any of the elements was `False`, indicating a non-numeric element.

Comment: Ah, this was very insightful. What I was missing was the fact that you can always wrap a function in another function (duh, it's functional programming). So I could just do

isNum  =  [ x | x <- xs, x `elem` ['0'..'9'] ] == xs

or even better

isNum  =  length [ x | x <- xs, x `elem` ['0'..'9'] ] == length xs

Comment: @August.  You're solution works, but it is not as efficient as using lists of `Booleans` because you are comparing the lengths of two lists, which traverses the entire list, as opposed to the Boolean functions which (partially) traverse one list.

Comment: Comparing the lists for equality is more efficient that comparing the lengths.

Comment: @vivian, only in the cases where the answer will be `False`.

Answer (score 3):

hint: use a list comprehension, not consist only of a list comprehension.

is there some list you can generate, and then run some further processing on to get the answer you need?

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, I'd just check that the list `[x | x <- xs, not (elem x ['0'..'9'])]` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

As small a hint as I can think of for the solution that first comes to my mind:

x `elem` ['0'..'9'] is useful for this, but not as a guard.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the homework requires a list comprehension, but the idiomatic way to do this would be:

```
import Data.Char
isNum = all isDigit
```

as a joke, if you want to think outside the box, you could throw in a list comprehension, but ignore it!

```
isNum =
    let unnecessaryListComprehension = [x | x <- [0..]]
    in all isDigit
```

or using a `Monoid`

```
import Data.Monoid
isNum xs = getAll $ mconcat [All $ isDigit x | x <- xs]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there is an answer marked as correct, I think the complete implementation will be like this:

```
isNum xs = foldr (&&) True [x `elem`['0'..'9'] | x <- xs] -- or

isNum xs = foldl (&&) True [x `elem`['0'..'9'] | x <- xs] -- or

isNum xs = and [x `elem`['0'..'9'] | x <- xs] -- Thanks for the comment of hammar

isNum "123" -- returns True
isNum "1a3" -- returns False
```

Comment: This fold [already exists in the Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:and). `and = foldr (&&) True`.

Comment: I just looked up foldl/foldr. I was unfamiliar with these functions and I'm trying to grok how this works. So the list comprehensions return a list of boolean values. Then calling `foldl/foldr  (&&) True` returns a function that returns the result of the logical and operation performed on True and the first item of the list. The function that is returned is then called on the second item of the list and so on and so forth. So the final result returned will just be True or False. Is that correct? This will also be more efficient than the solution I posted right? Thanks for the help

Comment: You are right about foldl/foldr (&&) True, final result will be True or False and since in Haskell logical operator are lazy, it will immediately return if it encounters with a False. However if all the values are True, then it will need to go to the end. Its efficiency may be same with the one that you check the equality of the lists.

Answer (score 0):

isNum xs =  null [ x | x <- xs, x `notElem` ['0'..'9'] ]

Just check the list is empty or not ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this partial function:

```
isNum :: [Char] -> Bool
isNum = foldl (\acc x -> acc && x `elem` ['0'..'9']) True
```

Example:

```
Prelude> isNum "111"
True
Prelude> isNum "111aaa"
False
```